# TextView display wrong when in ScrollView

Tags: android, textview

I get a weird problem when scroll a ScrollView which contains long TextViews.
Here's my xml code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroller"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Welcome to My Application" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#ff106510"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/longText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"

        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"

        android:text="@string/hello"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

            android:text="Accept" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

            android:text="Refuse" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

then I got what I want:
[image: The screen shot before scroll]

but when I scrolled, the problem happens:
[image]

Did this ever happen to you? I tested on a Emulator of SDK2.3.3, a HTC 2.2 prototype, this will always happen.
Can anyone help to tell me why this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the root cause:
As I defined my activity in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<activity
    android:name=".views.ScrollViewActivity"
    android:label="@string/scroll_view_sample"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.NoBackground">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.MY_CUSTOMER_INTENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

the NoBackground theme is defined like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.NoBackground" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and when I delete the line android:theme="@style/Theme.NoBackground", it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not missing a `</ScrollView>` at the end of your XML ?

**EDIT : BTW I try your XML in an Archos 70 2.2... no problem while scrolling.**